# Whats the best way to create templates using php?

Tags: php, html, templates

I have a class that gathers templates and displays the final output after connecting all the templates.

```
class Template{

$private $output = '';

public function Load_Template($template, $data = null){
    ob_start();
    include($template);
    $this->output .= ob_get_clean();
}

public function Display($add_footer = true){
    echo $this->output;
}

}
```

Now, Currently my templates look something like this.

```
<h1><?php echo $data['name']; ?></h1>
```

or the more complex ones that involve loops look more like

```
<ul>
  <li>
  <?php foreach($data as $user){ ?>
   <h1><?php echo $user['name']; ?></h1>
  <?php } ?>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Actually theres way more data than that in them, but im sure you guys get the point.
Now, I have heard people say thats it better to  have templates like this

```
<h1>{name}</h1>
```

or

```
<ul>
  <li>
   <h1>{name}</h1>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and then use a str_replace function... Now, if im using a foreach loop, how would I accomplish something like this... should i alter my class, and if so can i get some ideas as to how...  And do you guys suggest using templates with

Comment: You've heard people say that it's better to use templating languages, but do you agree with that? Is it really unacceptable for you to use PHP itself as a templating language?

Comment: You mentioned in one of your comments that you would rather create your own system because you heard Smarty was bad. One of the criticisms of smarty is that it creates basically another language that developers have to learn. The excuse for this is that you don't have to write all the <?php ?> tags. If that's what you want tick with Smarty which is mature and well tested. If you want to roll your own, stick with php. Smarty templates compile to php anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smarty is too redundant!  Your class with the function of cutting a page is enough.

Answer (score 1):

For these "{tags}" type template you have a very popular engine: [Smarty](http://smarty.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Every template language has its own way of approaching the problem.  You could, instead of writing your own template language from scratch, use one of the standard ones out there like Smarty.

If you are writing your own, you'll need at a minimum a construct that will let you express loops and conditionals.  One simple approach that I've seen used before is something like:

```
<!-- BEGIN conditional_or_looped_block_named_foo -->
Stuff that may appear zero or more times
<!-- END conditional_or_looped_block_named_foo -->
```

The syntax varies widely, of course, from one language to another, but the basic approach is the same: have some markup that surrounds the portion of code you want to isolate and repeat (or omit).

Comment: Okay, so i would need to create my own construct in my templates and then parse and replace them with regular php functions, and then continue like I had before. 

I've heard from a lot of people not to use smarty, for one reason or the other, so id rather just create my own.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea:
http://www.handyphp.com/index.php/PHP-Resources/Handy-PHP-Tutorials/Creating-Your-First-Template-Driven-PHP-Website-Part-2.html

I found it by doing a quick search, it has code to do what you are asking, it does search and replace with simply variables that you have created.

So your foreach() call would not echo but store in a variable, then you replace that variable with {users} in the template.